# I am using only one condition in case statement

Tags: sql, db2

```
SELECT
    CASE A.FILE_MAINT_TRX_CD  
        WHEN 'LOBC' THEN 'UPDATE' 
    END AS "TRANSACTION_TYPE"
```

Is there any other way to get the same result without using case statement for single condition?

This query is taking time with case statement is there any other way to get same result without using case statement?

Comment: You had **just asked** that very same question an hour ago - please **DO NOT** repost the same question over and over again!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `decode()`:

```
SELECT DECODE(A.FILE_MAINT_TRX_CD ,'LOBC','UPDATE') AS "TRANSACTION_TYPE"
```